# How to resize text on canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have found a way to be able to resize and squeeze my text on normal HTML5 Canvas with the following code:

```
$("input").on("input", function() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
var width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
if(width <= 100) {
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 100);
} else {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(100 / width, 1);
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 100);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

});

I want to do the same thing but with using the FabricJS. Is there a way that I can do it?

Comment: I wanted to clarify, that when the object frame is at the maximum width of the canvas and not resized on height (Y Axis), That is when I would like to have the text squeezed together if the text is too long.

Comment: Another restriction that i have also made it so objects are restricted to size of the canvas and they can not go off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah sure, just check the width of the text element after you've created it and set the ScaleX property if needed before adding it to the canvas:

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var t;

    canvas.renderAll();

    $("input").on("input", function () {
        if (t) {
            canvas.remove(t);
        }
        var textToDraw = $(this).val();
        t = new fabric.Text(textToDraw, {
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        if (t.width > c.width) {
            console.log('scale -> ' + (c.width / t.width));
            t.setScaleX(c.width / t.width);
        }
        canvas.add(t);
    });
```

If you wish to do this on object resize, use the modified event handler like so:

```
    function scaleText() {
        console.log("scale=" + t.getScaleX() + " w=" + t.getWidth());
        if ((t.width * t.getScaleX()) > c.width) {
            t.setScaleX(c.width / t.width);
        }
    }

    $("input").on("input", function () {
        if (t) {
            canvas.remove(t);
        }
        var textToDraw = $(this).val();
        t = new fabric.Text(textToDraw, {
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        scaleText();

        t.on("modified", function (options) {
            scaleText();
        });

        canvas.add(t);
    });
```

Comment: The problem that I am running into is that when someone resizes the text object that is when I need to be able resize the text, not before it has been written to the canvas.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, are you able to produce a jsFiddle or similar to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to do what you have mentioned but do it after the text has been written to the canvas.

Comment: I've added to the answer to show how this can be done when the user resizes the text object